# Counter not working when use if check

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on my button I am trying to check the label-category has been created

`($('#label-' + category_name).length === 0) {`

For some reason if i use  `($('#label-' + category_name).length === 0) {` it is stopping the counter.

> **Question:** How can I make sure that can get the counter to work when have this if `($('#label-' + category_name).length === 0) {`

I use codeigniter frame work also if that helps

Example how should perform [**here**](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/JWwQbw)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;

$(document).on('click', '.category_title', function(e){ 

    e.preventDefault();

    var category_name = $(this).attr('data-name');
    var category_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    if ($('#label-' + category_name).length === 0) {

        switch(counter) {
            case 0:
                element = 'label-default';
                break;
            case 1:
                element = 'label-primary';
                break;
            case 2:
                element = 'label-success';
                break;
            case 3:
                element = 'label-info';
                break;
            case 4:
                element = 'label-warning';
                break;
        }

        counter = (counter + 1) % 5;    

        html = '';
        html += '<li id="label-'+category_name+'">';
        html += '<span class="label ' + element + '">';
        html += category_name;
        html += '</span>';
        html += '</li>';

        $('.categories ul').append(html);

    }

    $('.categories-panel').html("");
});
</script>
```

Full code

```
<?php if ($categories) {?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php 
            foreach (array_chunk($categories, 4) as $category) {
            ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <?php 
                    foreach ($category as $category) {
                    ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <a href="#"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="media-heading" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                        <span 
                                            class="category_title"
                                            id="category_title" 
                                            data-name="<?php echo $category['name'];?>" 
                                            data-id="<?php echo $category['category_id'];?>"
                                        >
                                            <?php echo $category['name'];?>
                                        </span>
                                    </h4>
                                    <?php 
                                    echo $category['description'];
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;

$(document).on('click', '.category_title', function(e){ 

    e.preventDefault();

    var category_name = $(this).attr('data-name');
    var category_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    if ($('#label-' + category_name).length === 0) {

        switch(counter) {
            case 0:
                element = 'label-default';
                break;
            case 1:
                element = 'label-primary';
                break;
            case 2:
                element = 'label-success';
                break;
            case 3:
                element = 'label-info';
                break;
            case 4:
                element = 'label-warning';
                break;
        }

        counter = (counter + 1) % 5;    

        html = '';
        html += '<li id="label-'+category_name+'">';
        html += '<span class="label ' + element + '">';
        html += category_name;
        html += '</span>';
        html += '</li>';

        $('.categories ul').append(html);

    }

    $('.categories-panel').html("");
});
</script>
```

ask.php

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php 
    echo form_open(
        'questions/ask/submit', 
        array(
            'id' => 'post-form'
        )
    );
    ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="ask_title" 
                    id="ask_title" 
                    placeholder="Question Title" 
                    class="form-control" 
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea 
                    name="ask_message" 
                    id="ask_message" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    rows="15" 
                    placeholder="Your message..."
                ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="categories">
                <ul class="list-inline"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="category_name" 
                    id="category_name" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    placeholder="Choose category" 
                />
                <div class="categories-panel"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input 
                    type="submit" 
                    name="submit_button" 
                    id="submit_button" 
                    class="btn btn-default" 
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php echo form_close();?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#category_name").on('keyup', function(e){
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url('questions/ask/getcategories');?>',
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    category_name: $('#category_name').val()
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json){
                    $('.categories-panel').html(json);
                }
            });
        }); 
    });     
</script>
```

Comment: The given script it is running on a different page than the `ask.php`? Because I see in the first snippet of code you refer elements of the `ask.php`, while the JS code it is located in another code snippet.

Comment: @MerianosNikos Should I remove the ask.php from question

Comment: If you will hardcode category_name you will see that code works as it should. So the issue in $(this).attr('data-name');

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your answer is not clear enough, but I guess the following code can help you. The first time I press the button, the if statement works, as there's no label with the given ID. The second time, it doesn't as there's already an element with the given ID.

I guess that your problem is the way you set the ID. I tried your code, and I found that the statement `'<li id="label-'+category_name+'">'` is the issue.

If for example, the `category_name` is like that: `This Is A String` the label id it is going to be like this: `<label class="label-This Is A String">...</label>` that prevents the jQuery to match the element.

What I did in my case, was the replace the spaces with `-` and lowercase the string ( the lowercase it is not important ), and this way, the jQuery can now match the label ids.

Also keep in mind that if you use the string with special characters, you may also need to replace them as well.

```js
(
  function($, window, undefined) {

    var counter = 0;
    var button = $( '.category_title' );
    
    if ( 0 < button.length ) {
      button.on(
        'click',
        function ( e ) {
          e.preventDefault();
          
          var me = $( this );
          var category_name = me.attr( 'data-name' );
          var category_id = me.attr( 'data-id' );
          var id = category_name.replace( /\s+/g, '-' ).toLowerCase();
          var label = $( '#label-' + id );
          var label_class = '';
          
          if ( 0 === label.length ) {
            switch ( counter ) {
              case 0:
                label_class = 'label-default';
                break;
              case 1:
                label_class = 'label-primary';
                break;
              case 2:
                label_class = 'label-success';
                break;
              case 3:
                label_class = 'label-info';
                break;
              case 4:
                label_class = 'label-warning';
                break;
            }
          }
          
          counter = (counter + 1) % 5;

          html = '';
          html += '<li id="label-{id}">';
          html += '<span class="label {class}">';
          html += '{text}';
          html += '</span>';
          html += '</li>';
          
          html = html
                  .replace( /\{id\}/, id )
                  .replace( /\{class\}/, label_class )
                  .replace( /\{text\}/, category_name );

          $('.categories ul').append(html);
          
        }
      );
    }

  }
)(jQuery, this);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="category_title" data-name="This Is A Test" data-id="this-is-the-id">Click Me</a>
<div class="categories">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

*Note, I have also done a short refactoring to this code, in order to make it isolated from other code in your site.*

Comment: @wolfgang1983 did you try to check what my code does? I guess it can solve your issue. It seems like the problem starts when you set the ID of the label with spaces. Maybe if you try what I describe above, will solve your issue.

Comment: I tried it did not work on my end I have pasted full code in my question

Comment: Thank you so much for effort I have worked it out now added answer. Seem to need a couple of thins and and changed the location of script

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I understand. Sorry that I couldn't help even further but I feel like I am trying to solve an issue in a black box.

Answer (score 0):

WORKING NOW What I have done now is moved this script below over to the main ask.php view in my codeigniter

And I have added

```
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();

if ($('span[id="' + category_name + '"]').length > 0) {
    return false;
}
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;

$(document).on('click', '.category_title', function(e){ 

    var category_name = $(this).attr('data-name');

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('span[id="' + category_name + '"]').length > 0) {
        return false;
    }

    switch(counter) {
        case 0:
            element = 'label-default';
        break;
        case 1:
            element = 'label-primary';
        break;
        case 2:
            element = 'label-success';
        break;
        case 3:
            element = 'label-info';
        break;
        case 4:
            element = 'label-warning';
        break;
    }

    counter = (counter + 1) % 5;    

    html = '';
    html += '<li>';
    html += '<span id="' + category_name + '" class="label ' + element + '">' + category_name + '</span>';
    html += '</li>';

    $('.categories ul').append(html);

    //$('.categories-panel').html("");
});
</script>
```